# Designing multipage React app

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am planning phase of a web based app project. I want to use React JS on it.

This project will only serve to authenticated users. And I believe it will be a big project as the time grows.

With one page react app, I can redirect to login page but in the bundle.js every api URIs will be shown which I do not want to expose to public. So I think instead of creating one page app, I need to split to several base pages. This way I will not expose the api URLs to unauthorized visitors (Using separate login page).

I want to bundle every module separately. But in every module, there will be an react router with `browserHistory`.

- /login => separate page (after successful login, this will redirect to /dashboard)
- / or /dashboard seperate page
- /user => separate page but sub URLs will be handled by React Router. (ex: /user/profile, /user/status etc.)
- ... (for every main module there will be separate page

In backend, I will use PHP framework (probably lumen or laravel).

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This approach wont work when your user tries to directly visit /dashboard, the bundle will be downloaded regardless the user is logged in on not.
 
A better approach would be something like https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/latest/docs/guides/DynamicRouting.md serving bundles based on routes without actually generating multiple bundles(Apps). 
Instead of hiding your api endpoints you can use authentication headers for all your requests.
If you are using create-react-app this blog article is a good starting point https://www.drewbolles.com/blog/2016/11/14/webpack-code-splitting-with-create-react-app-react-router/

Comment: I was planning to redirect pages using backend framework. When user tries to visit /dashboard, the backend will redirect to login page without sending the bundle to browser.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am attempting to do the same thing with ReactJS and a Yii2 RESTful backend.